# How to add event to manually created popper element?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

The click event I added to the button does not work because the popper is automatically closed when clicking anywhere other than "props.children". How can I catch this click event? I can't access it via popper props or autocomplete props. Thanks in advance.

```
  const FilterPopper = (props) => {
    return (
      <Popper {...props}>
        <Box>
          <ButtonGroup>
            <Button>
              All
            </Button>
          </ButtonGroup>
          {props.children}
        </Box>
      </Popper>
    );
  };
```

```
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        limitTags={2}
        value={value}
        filterSelectedOptions
        PopperComponent={FilterPopper}
        disableCloseOnSelect
        autoSelect={true}
        options={options.length === 0 ? types : options}
        open={open}
        onOpen={() => {
          setOpen(true);
        }}
        onClose={() => {
          setOpen(false);
        }}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => {
          return <>{option?.name}</>;
        }}
        onChange={(event, value) => {
          if (value.length !== 0) {
            value.forEach((item) => {
              setValue(value);
              getIndex(item.id);
              filterDatas(item.code);
            });
          } else {
            removeFilter();
            setValue([]);
          }
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use react hook useRef and get exact object which is clicked.
Please check documentation with example
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref
This link will solve your problem for sure.
Thanks

Comment: I bind component to ref but then? The problem is already in the component it is deleted from the dom and the event is triggered.